# Can I view all instance variables in a project in one file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm using xcode and I was wondering if there was a way to view all instance variables in my project from one "central" file?

Comment: Just because I can't imagine what the purpose could be, why do you want to see a list of ivars without any context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your target, then choose Model > Class Model > Quick Model. In the resulting class diagram, show the Model Browser. Sort it on the Type column.

You can do a multiple selection on all the ivars and copy them to a text file.

If you save the Class Model file in your project, it will update as you add classes, ivars, and methods to the target.